# I am trying to add/remove class using the $event in Angular on (click)

Tags: angular

HTML: `(click)=togglePressed($event)`

```html
<div fxLayout="column">
  <h4>Push button to select service.</h4>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let service of services;">
    <button class="service-button" mat-raised-button color="primary" fxFlex (click)="updateTotal(service.cost); togglePressed($event);">{{service.name}}: {{service.cost | currency}}</button>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

TS:

```js
togglePressed(e : any) {
    let hasClass = e.target.classList.contains('pressed');

    if (hasClass) {
      console.log('removed the class')
      e.target.classList.remove('pressed');
    }
    else {
      console.log('Added the class')
      e.target.classList.add('pressed');
    }
  }
```

CSS:

```css
.pressed {
  color:black;
}
```

Summary: 
This works as it's adding/removing the class to the element in the DOM every time, but the button only changes color sometimes, and seemingly at random. I can't figure out why the UI doesn't update every time.

Comment: Can you provide the stackblitz with reproducible issue? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wzlz46

Comment: Use ngClass:https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're invoking two methods in your event. Unless you can include the logic inside `updateTotal()`, I can only guess it may be preventing `togglePressed()` to be invoked. Try switching the order to invoke `togglePressed()` first.

There is, however, a simpler way to do class toggling with `ngClass` provided by Angular. Add a new boolean property to your component's TS file.

```
public isPressed = false;
```

Then setup your DOM like so

```
<button 
  [ngClass]="{'service-button': true, 'pressed': isPressed}" 
  mat-raised-button 
  color="primary" 
  fxFlex 
  (click)="updateTotal(service.cost)"
>{{service.name}}: {{service.cost | currency}}</button>
```

`[ngClass}` will enable each class based on the boolean value assigned to it. Since we always want `service-button` to be present, we set it to `true`. But our `pressed` class will be set to our new boolean property.

Inside your `updateTotal()` method, you can add this single line at the beginning to trigger the state change.

```
public updateTotal(cost){
  this.isPressed = !this.isPressed;
  // Remaining updateTotal() logic.
}
```

Now each time the user clicks the button, the `pressed` class will toggle on and off.

Comment: you can also use ngClass in the way `[ngClass]="presed?'service-button isPressed':'service-button'"`

Comment: I took this approach, although used an array of boolean values that represented each button so they could be triggered individually. The updateTotal() method wasn't blocking, however I just felt there might be an easier way than to set up an array of flags. Thanks!